# Back Button On UINavagationController Missing The Arrow?

Tags: ios, back-button

I have a `leftBarButtonItem` and I am going to set it hidden in program, but I found the back button will be missing the arrow `<`

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.image = nil;
```

Comment: Are you not using the standard back button? Or have you created a custom one and assigned it to the `leftButtonItem`?

Comment: i have a custom left bar button on the UIViewController , but in some scenario, i want to remove the custom left bar button in program, so the default back button will shown. it works except the arrow is not showing correctly.

Comment: If you are not using the `leftBarButtonItem`, set it to `nil`, `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;`

Comment: I'll claim that one as a proper answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using the [`leftBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/leftBarButtonItem), set it to `nil`:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Just setting the `image` to `nil` will not work as the `UIBarButtonItem` would still be present.